# Model is not updating and rendering on the 'results' page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to update my model from an [HttpPost] The user enters their job title and I want to update the model and render it on a results page. However, its not updating the model based on the scope. Default is "Student" and I want it to display whatever the user inputs.

Model

```
public class InternshipModel {
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public string Major { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
Models.InternshipModel mod = new Models.InternshipModel() { Major = "Computer Science", Employer = "Random", Title = "Student" };

    //After Post method
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string major, string employer, string title) {

        mod.Title = title;
        UpdateModel(mod.Title);
        return RedirectToAction("Results", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult Results() {
        ViewBag.Message = "This is the results page.";
        ViewBag.Changes = mod.Title;  //Should expect user input, not default 'Title'
        return View();
   }
```

Comment: The web is stateless. `mod` is a new instance of your model each time you make a request. You need to persist your data (e.g. to a database) in the POST method and get it again in the GET method when you redirect

Comment: I eventually want to use the user input to query a database, any suggestions on going about that without storing the input into another database?

Comment: You could pass the value to the GET method - `return RedirectToAction("Results", "Home", new { title = title });` and add a parameter in the GET method - `public ActionResult Results(string title) {`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Your comments make more of the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to declare your model as static like

```
Public static Models.InternshipModel mod = new Models.InternshipModel() { Major = "Computer Science", Employer = "Random", Title = "Student" };
```

In `static` only one copy of your model will be created when the application starts and will reserve memory until the application stops thats why its **not suggested** .You can try the solution of Stephen since its a better way to achieve this.

Comment: A terrible solution - multiple request will be modifying the same object!

Comment: @StephenMuecke indeed its not a good solution. i have updated my and suggested your answer

Answer (score 1):

The `mod` variable that you have created (scope for the controller), resets each time you move out of the controller, or as @stephen in his comment mentions, it creates a new instance each time you make a request.

Here, you move out of the controller to the routing table when you return `RedirectToAction("Results","home");`

So, **the best way to deal with this issue is to save the model in a database and retrieve wherever you need it.**

Since you have mentioned, you would query the database with this details, It would be better to send this object as a whole or only the title to the Action you are passing it to. Like

```
return RedirectToAction("Results", "Home", new { InternshipModel = mod });
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Results", "Home", new { title = mod.Title });
```

and you would recieve them in the Action as parameters.

like :

```
public ActionResult Results(Models.InternshipModel mod)
{
      ViewBag.Message = "This is the results page.";
      ViewBag.Changes = mod.Title;  //User input, not default 'Title'
      return View();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple change you can do is adding static keyword before the object declaration. This will help you to initialise only one instance and your latest values will be reflected when object is invoked

```
Public static Models.InternshipModel mod = new Models.InternshipModel() { Major = "Computer Science", Employer = "Random", Title = "Student" };
```